# Nested If formula to determine a date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested-if

Seeking debugging help, I want a cell to output an X if the start date or due date fall within a certain month, however, when I run the formula on my column some cells do not have any text in them and they are outputting as "true". I need to fix the code so that the output in a cell that is blank (no text) is "false". here is what I have so far

```
=IF(OR(D5>=DATEVALUE("6/1/2017"), E5<=DATEVALUE("6/30/2017")), "X", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MONTH()

```
=IF(OR(MONTH(D5)=6,MONTH(E5)=6),"X","")
```

The issue is not limiting the dates to inside the month, to do it your way we need to bracket both dates:

```
=IF(OR(AND(D5>=DATEVALUE("6/1/2017"), D5<=DATEVALUE("6/30/2017")),AND(E5>=DATEVALUE("6/1/2017"), E5<=DATEVALUE("6/30/2017"))), "X", "")
```

[image]